Using .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) makes .searchable() initially visible, how to initially hide search bar until user scrolls up?
The default behavior in the absence of .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline), the search bar is not visible until the user scrolls up.
When .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) is applied, .searchable() is already visible.
I believe this is not the default behavior as Apple's own Messages app and Telegram has its navigation bar title set to inline, but the search bar is initially hidden.
Here's a sample code that produces the behavior:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var query = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello World")
             }
            .navigationTitle("Some title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // Comment this out
            .searchable(text: $query)
        }
        
    }
}

How do I retain the default behavior, such that the search bar is initially visually hidden while using .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)?
I tried using different configurations and still haven't attained the intended behavior. I tried narrowing down which parts of my code was causing the problem, and I narrowed it down to using .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline).
